# nodejs child process executing multiple times

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm using node child process to execute a python process get a url is reached. The thing is i'm getting the process running multiple times even though the url is being reached just one time.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
server.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('spawning process');
  var child = exec('python reporter.py', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error || stderr) return console.log(error, stderr);
    var data = JSON.parse(stdout);
    console.log('Process ready');
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you making a request to the server? Using `curl` or `wget`? Web browser?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that whatever you're using to send the GET response, is retrying that request when it's not getting a response. So put in a response:

e.g.

```
server.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('spawning process');
  var child = exec('python reporter.py', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error || stderr) return console.log(error, stderr);
    var data = JSON.parse(stdout);
    console.log('Process ready');
    res.status(200).send()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing the same issue in the latest version of node:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
 });
```

as per **nodejs.org**

// Capture your data in "data" and try putting your response in the "close".
  Close gets executed when all the data processing is completed.